# sum of particular column getting error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT  
    dbo.T_Order_Header.F_Exhibitor, 
    dbo.T_Order_Header.F_Exhibition, 
    dbo.T_Exhibition.F_Exhibition_Name,
    dbo.T_Exhibitor.F_Exhibitor_Name,
    dbo.T_Order_Detail.F_ItemCode,
    dbo.T_L2Category.F_L2Cat_Name, 
    SUM(dbo.T_Order_Detail.F_Qty-dbo.T_Order_Detail.F_CNQty) AS F_Qty,
    dbo.T_L1Category.F_L1Cat_Name,
    dbo.T_Order_Header.F_Stand,
    dbo.T_Category.F_Cat_name,
    dbo.T_ExStand.F_Bld_Code, 
    dbo.T_ExBuilding.F_Bld_name  
FROM dbo.T_Order_Header 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.T_OrderAttachment 
    ON dbo.T_OrderAttachment.F_OrderNumber  = dbo.T_Order_Header.F_OrderNumber 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.T_Order_Detail 
    ON dbo.T_Order_Detail.[Header_ID] = dbo.T_Order_Header.[ID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.T_L2Category 
    ON dbo.T_Order_Detail.F_ItemCode = dbo.T_L2Category.F_ItemCode
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.T_L1Category 
    ON dbo.T_L1Category.F_L1Cat_Code  = dbo.T_L2Category.F_L1Cat_Code
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.T_Category 
    ON dbo.T_Category.F_Cat_Code = dbo.T_L2Category.F_Cat_Code
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.T_ExStand  
    ON dbo.T_ExStand.F_Stand_Code = dbo.T_Order_Header.F_Stand
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.T_ExBuilding  
    ON dbo.T_ExStand.F_Bld_Code = dbo.T_ExBuilding.F_Bld_Code
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.T_Exhibition 
    ON dbo.T_Order_Header.F_Exhibition = dbo.T_Exhibition.F_Exhibition_Code
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.T_Exhibitor 
    ON dbo.T_Order_Header.F_Exhibitor = dbo.T_Exhibitor.F_Exhibitor_Code 
WHERE
    F_Stand IN(
        SELECT F_Stand_Code 
        FROM T_ExStand 
        WHERE
            F_Site_Code ='DWTC' 
            AND F_Bld_Code = 'HALL1-4 & CONCOURSE'
    )
    AND T_Order_Header.F_Exhibition = '12004'
    AND T_Order_Header.F_IsActive = 1 
    AND F_Exhibitor='2467'
```

I want to show sum of `F_qty` but I keep getting this error:

> Column 'dbo.T_Order_Header.F_Exhibitor' is invalid in the select list
>   because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the
>   GROUP BY clause

Comment: Please post the error.

Comment: if i add sum i am getting error like this:Column 'dbo.T_Order_Header.F_Exhibitor' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Post the query that contains `SUM`, with the error you are getting

Comment: You don't even have a `SUM` in your `SELECT`. How are you getting that error?

Comment: i edited my question

Comment: Ask yourself, sum of numbers in what rows are you trying to compute?

Comment: I think the error explains itself

Comment: sir other wise..i dont want to take Itemcode distinct is it possible?

Comment: Instead of `DISTINCT` try using `GROUP BY` and include all the columns in the `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by with all the columns which you're selecting (other than the one which is in the aggregate function), something like below query:

```
SELECT  
dbo.T_Order_Header.F_Exhibitor, 
dbo.T_Order_Header.F_Exhibition, 
dbo.T_Exhibition.F_Exhibition_Name,
dbo.T_Exhibitor.F_Exhibitor_Name,
dbo.T_Order_Detail.F_ItemCode,
dbo.T_L2Category.F_L2Cat_Name, 
SUM(dbo.T_Order_Detail.F_Qty-dbo.T_Order_Detail.F_CNQty) AS F_Qty,
dbo.T_L1Category.F_L1Cat_Name,
dbo.T_Order_Header.F_Stand,
dbo.T_Category.F_Cat_name,
dbo.T_ExStand.F_Bld_Code, 
dbo.T_ExBuilding.F_Bld_name  
 FROM dbo.T_Order_Header 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.T_OrderAttachment 
ON dbo.T_OrderAttachment.F_OrderNumber  = dbo.T_Order_Header.F_OrderNumber 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.T_Order_Detail 
ON dbo.T_Order_Detail.[Header_ID] = dbo.T_Order_Header.[ID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.T_L2Category 
ON dbo.T_Order_Detail.F_ItemCode = dbo.T_L2Category.F_ItemCode
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.T_L1Category 
ON dbo.T_L1Category.F_L1Cat_Code  = dbo.T_L2Category.F_L1Cat_Code
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.T_Category 
ON dbo.T_Category.F_Cat_Code = dbo.T_L2Category.F_Cat_Code
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.T_ExStand  
ON dbo.T_ExStand.F_Stand_Code = dbo.T_Order_Header.F_Stand
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.T_ExBuilding  
ON dbo.T_ExStand.F_Bld_Code = dbo.T_ExBuilding.F_Bld_Code
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.T_Exhibition 
ON dbo.T_Order_Header.F_Exhibition = dbo.T_Exhibition.F_Exhibition_Code
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.T_Exhibitor 
ON dbo.T_Order_Header.F_Exhibitor = dbo.T_Exhibitor.F_Exhibitor_Code 
WHERE
F_Stand IN(
    SELECT F_Stand_Code 
    FROM T_ExStand 
      WHERE
          F_Site_Code ='DWTC' 
          AND F_Bld_Code = 'HALL1-4 & CONCOURSE'
   )
   AND T_Order_Header.F_Exhibition = '12004'
  AND T_Order_Header.F_IsActive = 1 
  AND F_Exhibitor='2467'
 group by  dbo.T_Order_Header.F_Exhibitor, 
 dbo.T_Order_Header.F_Exhibition, 
  dbo.T_Exhibition.F_Exhibition_Name,
 dbo.T_Exhibitor.F_Exhibitor_Name,
 dbo.T_Order_Detail.F_ItemCode,
 dbo.T_L2Category.F_L2Cat_Name, 
 dbo.T_L1Category.F_L1Cat_Name,
 dbo.T_Order_Header.F_Stand,
 dbo.T_Category.F_Cat_name,
 dbo.T_ExStand.F_Bld_Code, 
 dbo.T_ExBuilding.F_Bld_name
```

Comment: hi,,,this also not solving my problem.is there any way i can take only item code without distinct?

Comment: Try removing Distinct keyword in this...

Comment: no mam..this also not solved my issue.actually if i add dbo.T_Order_Header.F_OrderNumber in my query my problem will solve.but i dont want to show this filed

Answer (score 0):

Use below query for your requirement.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT  
    dbo.T_Order_Header.F_Exhibitor, 
    dbo.T_Order_Header.F_Exhibition, 
    dbo.T_Exhibition.F_Exhibition_Name,
    dbo.T_Exhibitor.F_Exhibitor_Name,
    dbo.T_Order.F_ItemCode,
    dbo.T_L2Category.F_L2Cat_Name, 
    T_Order.F_Qty F_Qty,
    dbo.T_L1Category.F_L1Cat_Name,
    dbo.T_Order_Header.F_Stand,
    dbo.T_Category.F_Cat_name,
    dbo.T_ExStand.F_Bld_Code, 
    dbo.T_ExBuilding.F_Bld_name  
FROM dbo.T_Order_Header 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.T_OrderAttachment 
    ON dbo.T_OrderAttachment.F_OrderNumber  = dbo.T_Order_Header.F_OrderNumber 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(select  SUM(dbo.T_Order_Detail.F_Qty)-sum(dbo.T_Order_Detail.F_CNQty) AS F_Qty,
    [Header_ID],F_ItemCode from
     dbo.T_Order_Detail 
     group by 
     [Header_ID]) T_Order   ON dbo.T_Order.[Header_ID] = dbo.T_Order_Header.[ID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.T_L2Category 
    ON dbo.F_ItemCode.F_ItemCode = dbo.T_L2Category.F_ItemCode
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.T_L1Category 
    ON dbo.T_L1Category.F_L1Cat_Code  = dbo.T_L2Category.F_L1Cat_Code
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.T_Category 
    ON dbo.T_Category.F_Cat_Code = dbo.T_L2Category.F_Cat_Code
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.T_ExStand  
    ON dbo.T_ExStand.F_Stand_Code = dbo.T_Order_Header.F_Stand
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.T_ExBuilding  
    ON dbo.T_ExStand.F_Bld_Code = dbo.T_ExBuilding.F_Bld_Code
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.T_Exhibition 
    ON dbo.T_Order_Header.F_Exhibition = dbo.T_Exhibition.F_Exhibition_Code
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.T_Exhibitor 
    ON dbo.T_Order_Header.F_Exhibitor = dbo.T_Exhibitor.F_Exhibitor_Code 
WHERE
    F_Stand IN(
        SELECT F_Stand_Code 
        FROM T_ExStand 
        WHERE
            F_Site_Code ='DWTC' 
            AND F_Bld_Code = 'HALL1-4 & CONCOURSE'
    )
    AND T_Order_Header.F_Exhibition = '12004'
    AND T_Order_Header.F_IsActive = 1 
    AND F_Exhibitor='2467'
```

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 20
Incorrect syntax near '.'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 45
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'.

Comment: @jasbacker let me know whether the column F_Stand from t_order_detail table?

Comment: no sir..F_stand not in T_order Details

Comment: @jasbacker actually i missed from statement before t_order_detail table. please use from before    dbo.T_Order_Detail .

Answer (score 0):

You are using SQL `group` function. In this case you have to add `GROUP BY` clause at the end of the sql-statement. Please add all generic columns to `GROUP BY` clause except `F_Qty`. And remove `DISTINCT` from your select statement.